# Circle problem: What is the radius

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

Segment AB is tangent at A to the circle with center O,point D is interior to the circle, and segment DB intersects the circle at C. If BC=CD=3, OD=2, and AB=6, then find the radius of the circle.

Currently, I have thought about ways to use trigonometry to solve this problem, but none of them worked. Can you please help me tackle this problem?

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/11ll_gefQekm1MgBicdkBzvS17b8UOSp8MlFU9WN5Z4A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you made an image?

Comment: No, very sorry.

Comment: No, because the two lines are not collinear

Comment: Why is there someone called Anonymous Leopard on my drawing?

Comment: That is just a generic name: all the email addresses are anonymised to protect privacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta = ∠ODB$. We have 2 ways to get radius:

Law of Cosine on ΔODC: 
$$r^2 = 2^2 + 3^2 - 2(2)(3)\cos(\theta) = 13-12\cos(\theta)$$

Law of Cosine on ΔODB:
$$OB^2 = 2^2 + 6^2 - 2(2)(6)\cos(\theta) = 40-24\cos(\theta)$$
$$r^2 = OB^2 - AB^2 = 4-24\cos(\theta)$$
Combine both ways:
$$r^2 = 4-24\cos(\theta) = (2)(13-12\cos(\theta)) - 22= 2r^2 - 22$$
$$r = \sqrt{22}$$

Answer (score 0):

$OC$ is a median of $\Delta ODB.$

Thus, $$OC=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2OD^2+2OB^2-DB^2}$$ or
$$r=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\cdot2^2+2(r^2+36)-6^2}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $r=\sqrt{22}.$

I used the following.

In parallelogram $ABCD$ we know that:
$$AB^2+BC^2+CD^2+DA^2=AC^2+BD^2.$$
Let $AB=c$, $BC=a$, $AC=b$ and $BD=2m_b$, where $m_b$ be a median to $AC$ of $\Delta ABC$ .

Thus, $$2(a^2+c^2)=b^2+4m_b^2,$$ which gives
$$m_b=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2a^2+2c^2-b^2}.$$

Comment: How did you get the first equation about OC?

Comment: By the way even if the first equation is correct, r is about 1.981, which is impossible.

Comment: @user690234 I added something. See now.

Comment: @user690234 I fixed the typo. See again.

Comment: I can't see any difference with before.

Comment: @user690234 It was $r^2=...$. Now, it's $r=...$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Extend $BD$ to get the point $E$
at another intersection with the circle.

Using the power of the point $B$ 
with respect to the circle, we have

\begin{align}
|AB|^2&
=|BE|\cdot|BC|
=(|BD|+|DE|)\cdot|BC|
,\\
6^2&=(6+|DE|)\cdot 3
,\\
|DE|&=6
.
\end{align}

By the [Stewart’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem)
wrt $\triangle OCE$,

\begin{align} 
|OE|^2\cdot|CD|+|OC|^2\cdot|DE|
&=
(|CD|+|DE|)\cdot(|OD|^2+|DE|\cdot|CD|)
,\\
R^2(3+6)&=
(3+6)\cdot(2^2+3\cdot 6)
,\\
R^2&=22
.
\end{align}

Comment: what is stewart's theorem?

Comment: @user690234: [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem)
is a nice useful tool to have
along with the sine/cosine rules.